# In Django model, how to make a charfield automatic increase from A-Z

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I got `Question` and `Choice` model.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """ question """


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # index  ( from A-Z )
```

I want to show index for every choice in Django-admin `ChoiceInline` dynamically.

[image]

How to reach this?